Manga. Main character is a girl whose parents are a runaway noble and a knight
I forgot the title from when a read it a while back. I believe the main character and her mother had pink hair as well. I think there was also something related to her mother's family that she had run away from. I think it was in black and white, but I may be mistaken, and it could be a colored Korean work instead.
The family lives in a shack, with both parents alive, and I believe the mother is a mage, though I may be mistaken.

So which parent is the noble and which the knight? Or are they both nobles? Definitely pink hair and not blonde?

@qazmlpok I believe the mother was a noble and the father was the knight. As for the hair colors. Im not actually sure. I thought it was pink but I may have misremembered.

It isn't a good match, but Hilde Takes House Arpeggio is at least worth a quick check. Blonde haired protagonist; her mother was a noble magician that ran away; protagonist is also a mage. The father was not a knight, he was just handsome.

Do you recall any plot details of the story? How old is the protagonist? Any idea when you read this, and about how many chapters there were?

Unfortunately not. It was one of the many random works I had read in class to simply pass the time.

Wild guess, since this showed up in related question: Heartwarming Isekai Reincarnation Days? They live in a shack. Mother is runaway royalty, father used to be an adventurer.

sounds like the backstory to Otome Game no Heroine de Saikyou Survival . mc shares peach hair with her mother.
